# Artifactory & Groovy plugin - how to get a list of all repositories within Artifactory

Tags: plugins, groovy, artifactory

I'm writing an Artifactory plugin using Groovy.
I need it to get a list of all the repositories within the Artifactory.

In the lib folder of the plugin I added the jar of:

```
artifactory-java-client-services-2.3.2.jar
```

And the Intellij knows to complete the methods of the artifactory objects:[printscreen of the intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6qqr.png)

I was trying to write this in the groovy file:

```
import org.jfrog.artifactory.*
import org.jfrog.artifactory.client.*

....
....

def baseurl = <URL to the artifactory>
ArtifactoryClient artifactoryClient = new ArtifactoryClient();
def artifactory = artifactoryClient.create(baseurl, <the user name>, <the password>)
def allRepositories = artifactory.getRepositories()
```

But as I add the imports to the file, the console of the Artifactory is showing the following error:

```
2017-05-04 09:42:04,468 [art-groovy-plugins-reloader] [ERROR] (o.a.a.p.GroovyRunnerImpl:302) - Error loading script from '..\etc\plugins\test.groovy'.
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient due to missing dependency org/jfrog/artifactory/client/Artifactory

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient due to missing dependency org/jfrog/artifactory/client/Artifactory
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1091)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1069)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
        at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyScriptEngine.java:274)
        at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyScriptEngine.java:243)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:212)
        at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.loadScriptByName(GroovyScriptEngine.java:555)
        at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.GroovyRunnerImpl.loadScript(GroovyRunnerImpl.java:277)
        at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.GroovyRunnerImpl.getScripts(GroovyRunnerImpl.java:257)
        at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.GroovyRunnerImpl.reloadScripts(GroovyRunnerImpl.java:137)
        at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.GroovyRunnerImpl$ScriptsReloader.run(GroovyRunnerImpl.java:451)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient due to missing dependency org/jfrog/artifactory/client/Artifactory
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:391)
```

Any idea what is going wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to develop an Artifactory [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) and use the Artifactory [client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java) inside this plugin. While this is doable, it might not be the best approach.
User plugin should use the [Artifactory public API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-TheArtifactoryPublicAPI(PAPI)) (PAPI) for communicating with Artifactory.
For your use case you should be using the methods available in the [Repositories](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html) class for getting the list of available repositories.

The Artifactory client is actually using the Artifactory REST API behind the scenes, which is doable from a user plugin but slower than calling the PAPI directly. In addition the client requires to specify your Artifactory URL, which is an additional concern you will need to care about when writing the plugin.
If you do want to use the client in a user plugin, you should place the relevant .jar files (client and dependencies) in the [plugins lib directory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-PluginsLibDirectory).